# Spring Boot @ExceptionHandler with ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> Does Not Work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Consider the following code

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @GetMapping("download")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadCsv() {
       // service throws some runtime exception
       StreamingResponseBody body = outputStream -> service.writeToStream(outputStream);
       return ResponseEntity
              .ok()
              .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=\"file.csv\"")
              .contentType(MediaType.asMediaType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv")))
              .body(body);
    }
    
    /* Doesn't work */
    @ExceptionHandler(PermissionDeniedException.class)
    ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handlePermissionDeniedException(PermissionDeniedException e, HttpServletRequest req) {
       ErrorDetails details = ....;
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(errorDetails);
    }

    /* Also doesn't work */
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "Permission denied")
    @ExceptionHandler(PermissionDenied.class)
    void handlePermissionDeniedException2() {
    }
}
```

In the case of a runtime exception being thrown from `service.writeToStream(outputStream)`, the `@ExceptionHandler` for the exception *does* get called, however, the response returned by the controller does not have a body and will always have a HttpStatus 500.

If you do *not* return a `ResponseEntity` and instead return a `StreamingResponseBody` directly, everything works as expected.

```java
    /* 
      @ExceptionHandler works fine with this
    */
    @GetMapping("download")
    public StreamingResponseBody downloadCsv() {
       // service throws some runtime exception
       StreamingResponseBody body = outputStream -> service.writeToStream(outputStream);
       return body;
    }
```

Is there any way to make `@ExceptionHandler` work while wrapping the `StreamingResponseBody` in a `ResponseEntity` ?

Spring versions tried: 2.3.1.RELEASE, 2.3.2.RELEASE
Java Version: 11

Comment: can you share the code of your ExceptionHandler?

Comment: @Carlos i added examples of the two exception handlers i have tried to the sample code in the question body

Comment: Is it a typo that you're using `PermissionDenied.class` in the annotation instead of `PermissionDeniedException.class` (which is present among method parameters)?

Comment: are you intercepting the exception that is being thrown? Can you share the part of where you intercept for example "RuntimeException" in your exception handler

Comment: @amseager yes, sorry. Fixed that.  In debugger I actually see the exception handling method get invoked, however, the controller returns 500 status and no body no matter what

Comment: @Carlos not sure what you mean, I am not handling the exception anywhere else other than in the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method. While debugging, I see the method get invoked however it always returns a 500 error and no body instead of what's specified in the method.

Comment: ok I thought the ExceptionHandler might not be intercepting the exception, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Are you sure that the line `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(errorDetails);` can be reached? Maybe some error is thrown before this statement in exception handler?

Comment: @amseager here is project to reproduce https://github.com/austinarbor/spring-boot-streaming-response-issue . I'm not sure if I botched the tests though (this is my first time using StreamingResponseBody)...when running the tests the endpoints always return 200 status, but if you hit the same endpoint in the browser or CURL you get 500. Also `@ExceptionHandler` is not invoked from tests, but it is during normal operation

Comment: please chekc ControllerAdvice

Comment: @silentsudo `@ControllerAdvice` has the same issues